# Django no reverse for django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to use Django's built in authentication views for password reset, however I can't figure out why the application is bugging out for the built in authentication view `password_reset_confirm`. Any idea how I can fix this, or at least debug it? Been stuck on this issue for a while now.

**Template error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/

Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'token': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}' not found.


Error during template rendering

In template /home/user/Envs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 6

Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'token': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}' not found.

----> {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %} <---- Template errors here
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, password_reset, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_done, password_reset_complete

urlpatterns = patterns('userProfile.views',
    url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
        password_reset_confirm,
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
...)
```

**Attempted Solutions**

Per Joseph's suggestion, modifying the admin template fixes the problem. BUT, why can't I reverse the built in auth view???

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'userProfile:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code in the template

Comment: @Joseph It's indicated by the `---->` symbol. Specifically, this part: `{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`.

Comment: In what app does `urls.py` reside?

Comment: Can you try simply `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uid token %}`?

Comment: One thing I would try: Use the same URL pattern: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L16

Answer (score 3):

I believe since you've given the URL mapping a name, you can use just that name in the reversing:

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uid token %}
```

Assuming `uid` and `token` are in the context.

You might be able to do it the way you want to like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'django.contrib.auth.views',
    (r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'password_reset_confirm'),
)
```

Once you define a name though, I believe that's what you have to use for reversing it. Since your URL is not a tuple of string,string  but of string,function,string, you can't reverse on the name of the view function, but on the name of the URL pattern (that last string).

I may be mistaken here though.

[Second update]
The first argument in `patterns` is a prefix. You could try doing this instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, password_reset, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_done, password_reset_complete

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'...other_app_urls_here','other_view'),
...)
```

Or if you really want to keep the prefix for your app, just add the patterns seperately:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, password_reset, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_done, password_reset_complete

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('userProfile.views',
    ...userProfile_urls_here...
)
```

Either of those two solutions should allow you to reverse the whole builtin view.

Doc links:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#urlpatterns-view-prefix
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#multiple-view-prefixes

Comment: Yes, I followed your suggestion, see my edits. Any idea why I can't reverse the built in auth view?

Comment: See my additional update, I believe that explains it.

Comment: Can't get the built in reverse to work to save my life. Guess, I have to live with the template hack. It's pretty annoying! I even tried passing the `current_app` parameter to no avail.